# Finding maximum path of a complex array

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
$data = array(
  1 => array(
    "time" => 1,
    "parent" => array(4)
  ),
  2 => array(
    "time" => 3,
    "parent" => array(4, 5)
  ),
  3 => array(
    "time" => 2,
    "parent" => array(6)
  ),
  4 => array(
    "time" => 1,
    "parent" => array(6)
  ),
  5 => array(
    "time" => 1,
    "parent" => array(4)
  ),
  6 => array(
    "time" => 1,
    "parent" => array()
  )
);
```

Key is the ID of an element, parent is an array of elements, which refers to element id and time is just an integer.

This is an illustrated example of a given array:

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k06xu.png)

The integer on the bottom-left is the "id" and the integer in the middle is "time".

My goal here is find the most time-consuming path of this array. In the given example, the path would be 2->5->4->6 (id wise) resulting in 6 "time" overall. It looks pretty easy on paper, however I can't really seem to code an algorythm to get the elements of the most time-consuming path. I would appreciate any kind of help.

I think the algorythm should be kind of bruteforce-ish and check through all of the options available. Thus with the given array it would go like:

```
1 -> 4 -> 6 = 3
2 -> 4 -> 6 = 5
2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 6 = 6 
3 -> 6 = 3
4 -> 6 = 2
5 -> 4 -> 6 = 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: where did you get this array?

Comment: I tried various methods, but can't seem to get it working. This array is just a minified var_dump()

Comment: Weird structures (in schema) :) I'll need to get some sleep before getting aware of this. Good question +1

Comment: Modified a code a little bit. Hopefully this will be easier to understand.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to order the array based on the sum of the array values in `"parent" => array(4, 5)`

Comment: Out of the given array, I want to find the path which has the maximum sum of "time". I think this should be bruteforce-ish, checking all paths, finding the sums of each path and resulting the path with highest one. I'm sorry if I'm not being clear enough, I don't really know how I go about simplifting this.

Comment: Edited the question, maybe the algorythm parth should be a little more clear now.

Comment: It's a min-plus matrix multiplication... Instead of it being the shortest-path-algorithm, it's the longest-path-algorithm, but it uses the same principles: [Min-plus matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication). I've actually challenged my students in class on this subject: they have to write a program to achieve this. You're not one of them, are you? ;-)
This just being a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: You say you've tried various methods, please elaborate on that. As it says in the FAQ section of this site: a good question contains information on what you've tried so far, so that ppl don't waste their time writing up an answer, to which you'll reply _"I've tried this already, but..."_

Comment: @MartyMcVry thank you, I will try that.(and no, I'm definitely not one of your students :-)).

Comment: Use a recursive function that takes the list of what has already been added and looks for 'max of what's left'. Then add using that value and call itself again until no values are left. Return the max and start with the next initial value.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I have tried to make a recursive function, but ended up with just a lot of arrays.

Comment: @Tom why would this happen `2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 6 = 6`, i would think that it's like `2 -> 5 -> 6 = 4`, otherwise why would `2 -> 4 -> 6 = 5` not be like `2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 = 5` ? (that's if i don't take a look at the image)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV You're right, I've made a mistake. Fixed my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this will only work if there are no loops in the array.

```
// Note: built this in the SO editor, might have bugs
$cached = [];
$arrays = []; // Do this yourself

function get_path($num) {
    global $arrays, $cached;
    if (isset($cached[$num])) return $cached[$num];

    $array = $arrays[$num];
    $maxtime = $array['time'];
    $bestpath = array($num);
    foreach ($array['parent'] as $i) {
        $path = get_path($i);
        if ($path['time']+$array['time'] > $maxtime) {
            $maxtime = $path['time'] + $array['time'];
            $bestpath = array_merge(array($num),$path['path']);
        }
    }

    $cached[$num] = array('path' => $bestpath, 'time' => $maxtime);
    return $cached[$num];
}

var_dump(get_path(5));
```

Not really a bruteforce way, should be close enough to `O(n)`. The basic idea is that you just cache the paths it can take.

*Note: I used a bit of C-style syntax here, but ideally you wouldn't actually write the code like this*